# difference between postgresql-common and postgresql-contrib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am setting up a ubuntu instance for hosting a rails app... and when it got to the point where I install postgresql as the database, I opened two different resources to check it out, they are basically both almost the same apart from the difference:

one:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

and the other:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
```

so, leading to my very basic question: What is the difference between the `postgresql-contrib` and `postgresql-common` ?

Thanks all for responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question, this prompted me to actually look inside the full ist of files installed by these packages. Never occurred to me to do that before.

First you have to find out what versions are installed.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep postgres
```

I found that I have a mxtured of 9.3, 9.4 and 9.5 packages cluttering the system since that was my upgrade path. I inspected the 9.4 package as follows.

```
dpkg-query -L postgresql-contrib-9.4
```

You find that it contains `pg_archivecleanup` (in invaluable tool if you are using replication) and libraries and scripts for LTREE, HSTORE and many others.

Unlike contrib, postgresql-common doesn't have version number.

```
dpkg-query -L postgresql-common
```

Reveals interesting tidbits like the fact that it also contains `pg_archivecleanup`! other content includes the `pg_createcluster` and `pg_upgradecluster`.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the response... I am actually yet to install, so I can't really check the versions. Also, with your explanation, it looks like there is not really any major performance difference in the two. Is this correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with performance. These packages provide different components for management of the server or for extension. No harm installing both. In fact if you do something fancy you are definitely going to need both.

Comment: Oh... Okay then. Thanks again for the answer... :)

Comment: glad to have been of help